# where to implement window.onerror method on a react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to send my frontend logs to backend on react project. where can i implement window.onerror method so all of the unhandled exceptions will be thrown to backend within that method.

is it possible to write this method to app.js or something so all errors will be captured. Or should I add this method to all of my components

Comment: Consider using [Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html). In fact, production-level projects commonly use COTS products such as [Sentry](https://sentry.io/) for this.

Comment: _"is it possible to write this method to app.js"_... probably. Did you try? Did it not work?

Comment: @Phil  I tried and didnt catch any error. I might do something wrong what is the proper way do you know

Comment: @raina77ow As I know Error Boundaries are implemented for each html element I am trying to setup something generic

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Sure, each page should be wrapped into ErrorBoundary (or middlewared with COTS error reporting agents), but not each element in this page. Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: I found this post ( https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19613 ), it really explains usage of boundaries and uncaught errors and given code snipped is a really nice example but I am still facing problem that I don't get any uncaught errors. I will try to preproduce an error and try

Answer (score 0):

this post really helped me alot
[github.com/facebook/react/issues/19613](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19613)

I wrote below Event listener in src/index.js and it raises error

```
window.addEventListener('error', (event) => {
  console.log(Error(event.message ?? event));
  const { message, filename, lineno, colno, error } = event;
  console.log('Captured uncaught error:', message, filename, lineno, colno, error.stack);
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).